# Extract n bits and create int from Int32

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a `32 bit int` that has two value packed into it by a connected device.

The first 10 bits is X and the last 22 bits is Y.

How do I go about extracting these 2 numbers from the original int?

Comment: I'd expect to use the `&`, `|`, `>>` and `<<` operators (for masking, combining, and shifting respectively). Have you tried anything so far yet, whether using those operators or not?

Comment: With "first" you mean LSB or MSB?

Comment: Are X and Y signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bit-right-shifts operator [(>>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#right-shift-operator-) and and-bit-masks with the AND operator [(&)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int source = unchecked ((int)0xF45ABCDE);

        //10 LSB bits
        int X = source & 0x000003FF; //mask 10 LSBs

        //22 MSB bits: bitshift + mask
        int Y = (source >> 10) & 0x003FFFFF; 
                    
        Console.WriteLine("                  :MSB                          LSB");   
        Console.WriteLine("Source            :" + Convert.ToString(source, 2).PadLeft(32,'0'));
        Console.WriteLine("source shift >> 10:" + Convert.ToString((source >> 10), 2).PadLeft(32,'0'));
        Console.WriteLine("Mask X            :" + Convert.ToString(0x000003FF, 2).PadLeft(32,'0'));
        Console.WriteLine("Mask Y            :" + Convert.ToString(0x003FFFFF, 2).PadLeft(32,'0'));
        Console.WriteLine("X                 :" + Convert.ToString(X, 2).PadLeft(32,'0'));  
        Console.WriteLine("Y                 :" + Convert.ToString(Y, 2).PadLeft(32,'0'));
    }
}
```

output:

```text
                  :MSB                          LSB
Source            :11110100010110101011110011011110
source shift >> 10:11111111111111010001011010101111
Mask X            :00000000000000000000001111111111
Mask Y            :00000000001111111111111111111111
X                 :00000000000000000000000011011110
Y                 :00000000001111010001011010101111
```

Note, you'll need the mask if you are using `int`s, see: [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#right-shift-operator-)

> If the left-hand operand is of type int or long, the right-shift operator performs an arithmetic shift: the value of the most significant bit (the sign bit) of the left-hand operand is propagated to the high-order empty bit positions. That is, the high-order empty bit positions are set to zero if the left-hand operand is non-negative and set to one if it's negative.

Comment: That was perfect, and thanks for the explanation!